# How to use the CLI Options for Artisan to execute on a different Laravel Environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I am installing the migrate scripts for the first time on my application.
What I wish to do is use the configuration under /config/test/database.php to run my migrate installation scripts.

My entry on paths.php is the following

```
 $environments = array(
     'test' => array('http://test.*'),
     'local' => array('http://localhost.*')
);
```

My entry on /application/config/test/database.php

```
return array(
     'connections' => array(
     'mysql' => array('driver' => 'mysql',
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'database' => 'new_db',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => 'root',
     'charset' => 'utf8',
     'prefix' => '')
     ),
);
```

and /application/config/database.php

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array('driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'default_db',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '')
    ),
);
```

Every time I run `php artisan migrate:install --env=test` it always installs on the DB defined on /application/config/database.php and not using the configuration from /application/config/test/database.php.

Appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Am not sure if this is something that has been documented in Laravel for multiple environment. An additional parameter was required on the environment definition on the paths.php

```
$environments = array(
     'test' => array('http://test.*','MY_COMPUTER_NAME'),
     'local' => array('http://localhost.*')
);
```

Now, running `php artisan migrate:install --env=test` correctly executes the migration scripts on the DB configuration defined on /application/config/test/database.php.

Hope this helps others

Comment: You should always (where possible) use your computer name instead of a URL.

Comment: Well, I meant that one should specify the COMPUTER NAME as the second parameter for artisan --env to work is not something that is documented.